# How to write click event for viewchild element reference in angular 8

Tags: angular

Tried click event for element reference in typescript but not working.How to write click event for element reference.If anyone know please help to find the solution.

app.component.ts:

```js
@ViewChild('testElem') el:ElementRef;
@ViewChild('testElem2') el2:ElementRef; 

this.el.on('click',()=>{ 
  alert("test"); 
});
```

app.component.html:

```html
<div #el>testElem</div>

<div #el2>testElem2</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can make something like this:

**app.component.html**

```html
<div #el">testElem</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  
  @ViewChild('el', { static: false}) el: ElementRef;

  clickedElement: Subscription = new Subscription();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.clickedElement = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'click').subscribe(() => console.log('element clicked'));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // add this for performance reason
    this.clickedElement.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

We are using the `AfterViewInit` Hook because the DOM already exists here.

I hope I have been able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

With this, you don't need `@ViewChild` to write a click event.

**app.component.html**

```html
<div #el (click)="onClick()">testElem</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
// a method on the class
onClick() {
  console.log('element clicked');
  alert('test');
}
```

---

I strongly think you shouldn't be using the element reference for this, but if you truly must:

```js
@ViewChild('testElem') el:ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
  this.el.nativeElement.on('click',()=>{ 
    alert("test"); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Please use element reference

Comment: You shouldn't be using the element reference for that .. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved it by now, but for those who wondering..

Your `elementRef` reference is wrong, and you should call the event functions on the `nativeElement` property of `elementRef`.

This should work:

app.component.html:

```
<div #el>testElem</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('el') testElement: ElementRef; 

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.testElement.nativeElement.onmouseenter = () => console.log('mouse enter')
  this.testElement.nativeElement.onclick = () => console.log('clicked')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible (an alternative) to use the Renderer2 service for listening to events on elements.

```
@ViewChild('testElement') element : ElementRef;
```

Inject the Renderer2 service

```
constructor(renderer2: Renderer2) {}
```

Add the event listener

```
this.renderer2.listen(this.element, 'click', () => { ... });
```