# Click method on @Viewchild element not working

Tags: angular

I'm trying to simulate a click on a button in Angular. But it's not working. I imported `ViewChild` and `ElementRef`. Then added the hash reference to the button. and then called the click but it's not working. this is the HTML:

```
  <button #filterPanelButton id="loadFiltersButton" class="details-filters-button" mat-button [ngClass]="{'filter-button-active': loadButtonChanged}"
        type="button"[matMenuTriggerFor]="loadDetailsFilter" (menuOpened)="detailsFiltersOpened()">
        <span id="loatFilterButtonText" class="details-filters-button-text">{{loadButtonText}}</span>
        <mat-icon class="menu-active" [ngClass]="{'menu-open': arrowUp}">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

and this is the .ts method:

```
lauchSearchAndCLoseFiltersPanel($event){
    this.detailsFiltersClosed($event);
    // document.getElementById('loadFiltersButton').click();
    this.filterPanelButton.nativeElement.click();
}
```

If I uncomment the `document.getElementById('loadFiltersButton')` it works, but I've heard that it is discouraged to use that method in Angular.

Why might the viewChild method not be working?

Comment: Share complete code that makes the ```@ViewChild()``` part visible and whatever other codes that can make us understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: What you want to do is click on the button and send some data to your .ts file right? Why not simply use built-in (click) event? If you are set on using ViewChild with click , you can use the method in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004074/how-to-write-click-event-for-viewchild-element-reference-in-angular-8

Answer (score 2):

the correct way would be not to work with low level events, but to call the openMenu

```
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger

lauchSearchAndCLoseFiltersPanel(){
    this.trigger.openMenu();
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the problem is that 'mat-menu' is not a nativeElement. I think that's why it doesn't accept the '.nativeElement' method... So how can I attach a click if I can't use nativeElement?

Comment: you can query the element ref via `@ViewChild(..., {read: ElementRef})`. but usually if you need a elementRef  then you really really need to manipulate the html element, or you are doing something terribly wrong, so I would stick to calling `openMenu` method

Answer (score 2):

You probably got the `MatButton` class but in your case you need to make sure that you get the `ElementRef` from your `@ViewChild` decorator. To do that you can pass a second argument with a `read` property and explicitly set it to `ElementRef` like so:

```
@ViewChild('filterPanelButton', { read: ElementRef }) public filterPanelButton: ElementRef;
```

And now this should work:

```
this.filterPanelButton.nativeElement.click();
```

See also [the answer on a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37476195/1697459).

Check for more information about the `ViewChild` and its `read` property also [the official Angular documentation here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description).

> **read** - Used to read a different token from the queried elements.

So if you're querying a `MatButton` with your selector (or another material component), you won't be able to get the `nativeElement` since you get the reference to the material component and not to the `ElementRef`.